# Does simplemembership implement password format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

In ASP.NET membership you can define rules for pasword like this:

```
...passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=.{5,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d])" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" />
```

Does SimpleMembership have a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure the password rules in SimpleMembership as you did for ASP.NET Membership. The password is always hashed. You can check the password strength and rules yourself in the application by validating it against rules during the registration and password reset process. Of course this only make sense if you are not using OAuth support that SimpleMembership provides.